# Could you help about the problem that the frame in tkinter only shows once

Tags: python, tkinter

I just learn a little about python and tkinter.I have a problem that I just want to create a class about a calculator,but what's wrong is that the interface just show once.Once I press the button,the calculator's interface just disappear.This is the code.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


class EasyCalculator:
        def __init__(self):
            self.root = Tk()
            self.s = ''
            self.Laststring = []
            self.easymode = Frame(self.root,height=450,width=320,bg='pink')
            self.root.geometry('320x450')
            self.root.title('Calculator')

        def Calculate(self,string):   
            result = eval(string)
            return result

        def renew(self,strings):
            self.Laststring.append(self.s)
            self.s = self.s + strings
            if('<-' in self.s):
                self.Laststring = Laststring[:-1]
                self.s = self.Laststring[len(self.Laststring)-1]
                self.funcpr(self.Laststring[len(self.Laststring)-1])
                self.show()
            elif('=' not in self.s and 'AC' not in self.s):
                try:
                    self.funcpr(self.s)
                    
                except:
                    messagebox.showinfo('Warning','Oops,something wrong!')
                    
            elif('AC' in self.s):
                try:
                    self.s = ''
                    self.funcpr('                                                               ')
                    
                except:
                    messagebox.showinfo('Warning','Oops,something wrong!')
        

            else:
                s2 = self.s.strip('=')
                result = self.Calculate(s2)
                self.s = self.s + str(result)       
                self.funcpr(self.s)
                self.s=''
                


        def funcpr(self,t):     
            Label(self.easymode,text = t).grid(row = 0,column=0,columnspan = 4,rowspan = 2)

            
        def CalWindows(self):    #interface
            Button(self.easymode,text='1',command=lambda:self.renew('1')).place(x = 0,y = 200,width = 80,height = 50)
            Button(self.easymode,text='2',command=lambda:self.renew('2')).place(x = 80,y = 200,width = 80,height = 50)
            Button(self.easymode,text='3',command=lambda:self.renew('3')).place(x = 160,y = 200,width = 80,height = 50)
            Button(self.easymode,text='+',command=lambda:self.renew('+')).place(x = 240,y = 200,width = 80,height = 50)
            Button(self.easymode,text='4',command=lambda:self.renew('4')).place(x = 0,y = 250,width = 80,height = 50)
            Button(self.easymode,text='5',command=lambda:self.renew('5')).place(x = 80,y = 250,width = 80,height = 50)
            Button(self.easymode,text='6',command=lambda:self.renew('6')).place(x = 160,y = 250,width = 80,height = 50)
            Button(self.easymode,text='-',command=lambda:self.renew('-')).place(x = 240,y = 250,width = 80,height = 50)
            Button(self.easymode,text='7',command=lambda:self.renew('7')).place(x = 0,y = 300,width = 80,height = 50)
            Button(self.easymode,text='8',command=lambda:self.renew('8')).place(x = 80,y = 300,width = 80,height = 50)
            Button(self.easymode,text='9',command=lambda:self.renew('9')).place(x = 160,y = 300,width = 80,height = 50)
            Button(self.easymode,text='X',command=lambda:self.renew('*')).place(x = 240,y = 300,width = 80,height = 50)
            Button(self.easymode,text='AC',command=lambda:self.renew('AC')).place(x = 0,y = 350,width = 80,height = 50)
            Button(self.easymode,text='<-',command=lambda:self.renew('<-')).place(x = 80,y = 350,width = 80,height = 50)
            Button(self.easymode,text='%',command=lambda:self.renew('%')).place(x = 160,y = 350,width = 80,height = 50)
            Button(self.easymode,text='/',command=lambda:self.renew('/')).place(x = 240,y = 350,width = 80,height = 50)
            Button(self.easymode,text='.',command=lambda:self.renew('.')).place(x = 0,y = 400,width = 80,height = 50)
            Button(self.easymode,text='0',command=lambda:self.renew('0')).place(x = 80,y = 400,width = 80,height = 50)
            Button(self.easymode,text='=',command=lambda:self.renew('='),bg='Orange').place(x = 160,y = 400,width = 160,height = 50)
            

        def show(self):
            self.easymode.pack()
            self.CalWindows()
            self.root.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    Calculator1 = EasyCalculator()
    Calculator1.show()
```

My appreciate!!Thank all of you who try to help me!!

Answer (score 1):

In the method `funcpr` you grid the label inside the Frame `self.easymode`. This makes the Frame `self.easymode` shrink to contain only the label.

You can prevent this by having the frame `self.easymode` expand and use the whole containing widget:

```
def show(self):
    self.easymode.pack(expand=True, fill='both') # Expand frame
    self.CalWindows()
    self.root.mainloop()
```